# Programmatically Creating An User Account Linked To An Existing Order

Tags: guest-checkout, create-account, user-account

We've got a website where users can purchase several products, which then redirects users to the shopping cart ready to checkout. We are skipping account creation so all of these purchases start off as belonging to Guest Accounts.

Afterwards, they are redirected to another site where they create an account for our application. Ideally, we'd be able to programmatically create an User Account for this guest using the same credentials provided for our account creation. They would then be informed of this via email.

Crucially, we need the purchase to be linked to the specific account in order for us to handle recurring payments linked to the products that we are selling.

Any help or advice regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this free extension, if that help you : https://magecomp.com/magento-2-assign-order-to-customer.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code stamp:

```
if ( $order->getId() && !$customer->getId() ) {
                    $customer = $this->orderCustomerService->create( $orderId );
                    $order->setCustomerGroupId( $customer->getGroupId() );
                    $this->orderRepository->save( $order );
                    return $this->messageManager->addSuccess( 'Customer created successfully.Check your email to continue.' );
                } else {
                    //if already registered then assign to it
                    $order->setCustomerId( $customer->getId() );
                    $order->setCustomerIsGuest( 0 );
                    $order->setCustomerGroupId( $customer->getGroupId() );
                    $this->orderRepository->save( $order );
```